# Qt Creator with MSVC10 compiler and OpenCV link

Tags: debugging, opencv, qt-creator, visual-studio-2010

I succesfully compiled and debugged through projects having no 3rd party libraries, using Qt Creator 2.7.2 with MSVC10 kit.

Later on, I decided to include OpenCV and tried to debug. I am having no errors or warnings. However, the debugger for MSVC10 seems to be not working. Main window does not show up.

If I use release build; everything works perfectly, but just I can't develop without debugger.

I searched through forums but I had no luck except this unresolved thread: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17152

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you are using Qt or Visua Studio, so if you could specify that would be great.

If you are using Visual Studio:
Maybe for some reason compiler/linker doesn't generate debug information. Check whether there is a `/DEBUG` flag in linker command line (project properties->CONFIGURATION PROPERTIES->linker->command line)

If your release configuration is working fine, you may try to debug in release mode - just set project properties->CONFIGURATION PROPERTIES->linker->debugging "generate debug info". Note that this solution has some disadvantages(comparing to "normal" debugging).

If you are using Qt Creator:
Sorry, i can't help you. Maybe consider using Visual Studio? :)

Comment: :) I used qt addin for VS and build up many opencv projects + GUIs before. But because of the fact that qt creator has better design mechanism than qt designer; I wanted to switch to qt IDE. I actually solved my issue. I noticed that, when I try to run debug application, qt linker couldn't locate the dll files. I added them all to the app path by hand. Now I'm having no errors.